# get real client ip address in dotnet core when using nginx

Tags: nginx, .net-core

I'm using dotnet core. I'm grabbing the IP address using the line `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()`. When I visit my site using my ip address I see the client ip address showing correctly. However I want to use https and I use nginx. So in my location I wrote

```
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
```

When I visit my site through the domain my ipaddress shows as `::1` and `127.0.0.1` (they switch every time I refresh). My nginx config is below I'm not exactly sure how to tell .net core the real ip address

---

```
server {
    server_name         www.example.com;
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    root                /var/www/example.com/;
    add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    index index.html index.htm;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    #try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
    expires max;
    default_type text/plain;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    index off;
    location ~/other/ {
        index off;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /abc {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5050;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Forwarded headers are not processed by default. You need to use HttpOverrides middleware.

- add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides` as dependency
- add the following to your `Configure` method:

  ```
  app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
      {
          ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
          ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
      });
  ```

Comment: After the dependency adding you can call it with this  code: var ip = this.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault();if (ip.Contains(","))
    ip = ip.Split(',').First().Trim();

Comment: @ProjectMayhem NO! You shouldn't. Instead you should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides` and it will take care the rest for you.

Answer (score 2):

I am using .Net Core 2.2, and found the following to work.  It's slightly different than the other answer (which I couldn't get to work).

- Add *Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides* as dependency
- Add the following to the *ConfigureServices* method:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

- Add the following to the *Configure* method:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Source: [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: This worked for me here with ASP.NET Core 7.x - thanks for providing the link so I could check official docs too. 