# ASP.Net Core Detect real client IP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ip

I've got an ASP.NET Core app hosting on IIS, the server with which is behind the router. I need to detect real clients IPs. From the local network `context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` returns correct IP, but from the outside it is always `127.0.0.1`.

Also I tried to look at `X-Original-For` header which locally gives `127.0.0.1` and nothing form the outside.

I tried `UseForwardedHeaders` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450563/4801505) middleware but as I got it the middleware is already used by `UseIISIntegration` (https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384) so there is no sense using it twice.

So, can I achieve the thing at all in my circumstances? Maybe some IIS config required?

Comment: Use `X-Forwarded-For`

Comment: Were you able to solve this @Slip?

Answer (score -1):

Use the external link to get ip address.

I end up using

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var ip = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org");
```

If you are using any language other than C# refer to website [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/)